# Why does Ago become agit, agitis, agis, etc? [conjugate with an *i*?]

Tags: classical-latin, morphology, conjugation

I am working on word endings in Latin, and I came across the word *Ago*.
And I was looking at the different conjugations for this word and it did not make sense to me.

Observe:

Endings are:

```
         o/m   |   mus

         s     |   tis

         t     |   nt
```

But, when *ago* is conjugated, this happens:

```
        Ago | Agimus 

       Agis | Agitis          

       Agit | Agunt
```

Why is it conjugated with an *i*?

Comment: It belongs to the third conjugation. Most verbs in the 3rd conjugation form the different persons of the present tense the same: -o, -is, -it, -imus, -itis, -unt. Thus lego-legis, scribo-scribis, etc. Or do you mean how did the 3rd conjugation evolve to get to that?

Comment: @Rafael, I think the question is why the third declension uses *-i-* (and *-u-*!) or how things evolved that way. A simple answer is "to avoid consonants in the endings colliding with consonants in the stem", but I doubt that would be satisfying.

Comment: To keep it simple, 3rd conjugation is ALMOST* always: {an O, 4 I's, and a U}. Hope this helps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're asking how the third conjugation historically came to use the vowels *i/u*, it has to do with regular sound changes that affected the original Proto-Indo-European (PIE) endings.

The present indicative active paradigm for this verb in PIE, with its descendant paradigm in Latin, would look something like this:

> 1sg. *h₂eǵ-ō > agō
>   2sg. *h₂eǵ-e-si > agis
>   3sg. *h₂eǵ-e-ti > agit
>   1pl. *h₂eǵ-o-mos > agimus
>   2pl. *h₂eǵ-e-tes > agitis
>   3pl. *h₂eǵ-o-nti > agunt

In PIE, as you can see, the personal endings were preceded by a so-called "thematic vowel", either *e* or *o* (except in the 1sg.). This vowel then underwent the following changes in Latin:

1. In non-initial open syllables, all vowels (basically; there are some exceptions) in Latin became *i*. This is the source of the *i* in *agimus, agitis*.
2. *e* became *i* before a word-final consonant. This is what happened in *agis, agit*, where first the final *-i* of the PIE form was lost (as also in the 3pl.), leaving the *s/t* word-final.
3. *o* became *u* before a nasal (again not absolutely always, but in many cases). This gives the *u* of *agunt*.

Comment: While I doubt that this what the OP was wondering about, this is too great not to upvote :)

Comment: @TKR, Although it doesn't help me conjugate the verb, I can now understand why in the world it would suddenly conjugate to something like 'agit'. (I know I will learn to conjugate more effectively later on, so that is not really a big deal!) Thanks so much for the input - I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 9):

To ask “why” is inevitably a question about etymology and Indo-European (IE) comparative linguistics. The Latin 3rd conjugation continues IE thematic presents. There is a root, then the “thematic vowel” *e or *o, and then the personal ending. In Latin *e regularly becomes /i/ before /s/ and /t/. Thus IE *bher-e-ti becomes bharati in Sanskrit, but *ferit > fert in Latin, while *bher-o-nti becomes Sanskrit bharanti, and Latin ferunt. Does that make it any clearer? I am not sure that it does. Reconstructed languages are just as inscrutable as real ones.